# Is it possible to connect Kinect to Unity3D and compile it to run on Jetson TK1?

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, nvidia, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I am working on a project which runs on a Linux PC. However I want to try a new combination. I want to connect Microsoft Kinect to NVIDIA Jetson TK1. Then run a "game" compiled with Unity3D for Linux, which uses the Kinect as an input. Is this possible after all? I found post connecting Kinect to Jetson TK1, There are SDK's connecting Unity and Kinect (mostly Windows), but I couldn't find anything useful for my project.

Answer (score -1):

Unity doesn't support ARM Linux build target, and it sounds like they don't plan to: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/arm-support.357866

It may be possible to run Android on the Jetson TK1, and run an Android app built with Unity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523202/android-on-jetson-tk1

I'm trying to figure this out as well.

Then you'd have to get the Kinect working on Android...